# Is TFS exclusive checkout possible for one project only?

Tags: tfs

At first I want to apologize because it's for sure a silly question, but I'm not an administrator but a software developer.

As far as I know there's an option in TFS named

> Check out - Prevent other users from checking out and checking in

I want to ask about a scope of this setting. Is it possible to turn it on/off for a single project or only for a whole server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setting is configured per Team Project and cant be set at the server level.

However if you use local workspaces t is ignored as the client does not tell the server what is checked out.